# PHP MYSQL LEFT JOIN 3 Tables

Tags: php, mysql

i have a problem about LEFT JOIN MYSQL.

```
id_product // product table
----------
    1
    2
    3

id_comment | id_product // comment table
----------   ----------
    1            1
    2            2
    3            3

id_reply | id_comment | id_product // reply table
--------   ----------   ----------
    1           1            1
    2           2            2
    3           3            3

"SELECT 
    `product.id_product`, `reply.id_comment`,
    `comment.id_comment`, 
    `COUNT(comment.id_comment) AS allcomment`,
    `COUNT(reply.id_reply) AS allreply`

FROM product

LEFT JOIN comment ON comment.id_product = product.id_product
LEFT JOIN reply ON reply.id_product = product.id_product AND reply.id_comment = comment.id_comment"

GROUP BY product.id_product"

$sumComment = $joinFetch['allcomment'] + $joinFetch['allreply']; // get total comments
```

the output bring **more** than i expected. actually it must be **6**. 3 + 3 = 6

first, it's working perfect with only one LEFT JOIN but when i add another LEFT JOIN which is reply table. the problem occure.

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Perhaps you can provide the desired output

Comment: Can you please be specific on what exact output you need to see? So, that it can be addressed!